# how can I make methods inside an object

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I need help with my homework. I don't know how to make a method inside the object like what he wants:

> create a monkey object, which has the following properties: name,
>   species, foodsEaten.
>
> And the following methods:
>
> eatSomething(thingAsString)
>
> introduce: producers a string introducing itself, including its name,
>   species, and what it's eaten.
>
> -Create 3 monkeys total. Make sure all 3 monkeys have all properties set and methods defined.

I already created the monkey object with its properties:

```
function Monkey(name, species, foodsEaten) {
    this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
    this.foodsEaten = foodsEaten;
}

let monkey01 = new Monkey(chimp, chimpanzee, honey);
let monkey02 = new Monkey(gibb, gibbon, apple);
let monkey03 = new Monkey(babo, babbon, banana);
```

Comment: That looks like a function to me. Not an object. An object would be like `var monkey = { name: "monkey01", age: "10" }` etc.

Comment: @SultanBandar please explain you method. What is expected output of it?

Comment: @Aniket G it is more specifically a constructor, to create new objects with predefined properties, as done in last 3 lines of code

Answer (score 2):

The way you would typically do this is by adding a function on the `Monkey` prototype. This will allow all instances to share the same function. Within the function you can refer to the instance with `this` (assuming you call it from the instance such as `monkey01.eatsomething()`).

Here we make `foodsEaten` an array so you can keep track of more than one. The method then just pushes into `this.foodsEaten`:

```js
function Monkey(name, species, foodsEaten) {
  this.name = name;
  this.species = species;
  this.foodsEaten = [...foodsEaten];  // make a copy so you don't mutate the passed in array.

}

Monkey.prototype.eatsomething = function(foodString) {
  this.foodsEaten.push(foodString)
}

let monkey01 = new Monkey('chimp', 'chimpanzee', ['honey']);

monkey01.eatsomething("bananna")

// now it's eatne more food
console.log(monkey01.foodsEaten)
```

For the other methods just do more of the same.

Comment: Is there any special thing in defining the method outside and not inside the object definition? Like for example: `this.eatsomething = function(foodString) { ... }`. Just curious, nothing more...

Comment: @Shidersz It's more efficient to put it on the prototype. This way there is only one function and all instances reference it. When you put the definition in the constructor, each instance makes a unique copy of the function.  Additionally prototypical inheritance works when the function is on the prototype. For example, you could make a chimpanzee class that is able to inherit the monkey methods.

Comment: I see, thank you, this clarify will help him too! Is the same valid if we use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

Comment: @Shidersz if you use classes the methods will end up on the prototype like I have above.

Comment: Thank you again! Sorry if I bother your,  I just was curious about your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach public methods to JS functions in a similar way as you assign variables.

```js
function Monkey(name, species, foodsEaten) {
  this.name = name;
  this.species = species;
  this.foodsEaten = foodsEaten;
  this.doSomething = function (thing) {
    console.log('do something with', thing);
  }
}

let monkey01 = new Monkey('chimp', 'chimpanzee', 'honey');

monkey01.doSomething('banana');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function, not a object. But assuming this is what you wanted, you could use the code below.

```js
function Monkey(name, species, foodsEaten) {
  this.name = name;
  this.species = species;
  this.foodsEaten = foodsEaten;
  this.eatSomething = function() {
    console.log(`I am ${name}. I am part of the ${species} species, and have eaten ${foodsEaten}`);
  }


}

let monkey01 = new Monkey("chimp", "chimpanzee", "honey");


let monkey02 = new Monkey("gibb", "gibbon", "apple");


let monkey03 = new Monkey("babo", "babbon", "banana");

monkey01.eatSomething();
```